# SemanticImport vs Import differ on same CSV file?

Tags: bugs, import

Using WL 12.1.0. Is `SemanticImport` caching data somewhere? I did this `SemanticImport` for the first time, yesterday. Worked fine. Today it misses the last column (date). However, `Import` correctly retrieves everything including the last column. Is there a way to force `SemanticImport` to get the latest data? I know I can work around by using `Import`, but I'd like to use `SemanticImport` so that I can work with `Dataset`. Here is an excerpt of my notebook:

`SemaniticImport` drops the last column in the following import:

```
cv19Deaths = 
  SemanticImport[
   "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/\
csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-\
Deaths.csv"];
```

Whereas `Import` correctly imports the last column:

```
cv19DeathsCSV = 
  Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/\
master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-\
covid-Deaths.csv"];
```

Looking at the `Keys`:

```
cv19Deaths[1] // Normal // Keys

Out[]:= {"Province/State", "Country/Region", "Lat", "Long", "1/22/20", \
"1/23/20", "1/24/20", "1/25/20", "1/26/20", "1/27/20", "1/28/20", \
"1/29/20", "1/30/20", "1/31/20", "2/1/20", "2/2/20", "2/3/20", \
"2/4/20", "2/5/20", "2/6/20", "2/7/20", "2/8/20", "2/9/20", \
"2/10/20", "2/11/20", "2/12/20", "2/13/20", "2/14/20", "2/15/20", \
"2/16/20", "2/17/20", "2/18/20", "2/19/20", "2/20/20", "2/21/20", \
"2/22/20", "2/23/20", "2/24/20", "2/25/20", "2/26/20", "2/27/20", \
"2/28/20", "2/29/20", "3/1/20", "3/2/20", "3/3/20", "3/4/20", \
"3/5/20", "3/6/20", "3/7/20", "3/8/20", "3/9/20", "3/10/20", \
"3/11/20", "3/12/20", "3/13/20", "3/14/20", "3/15/20", "3/16/20"}
```

```
cv19DeathsCSV[[1]]

Out[]:= {"Province/State", "Country/Region", "Lat", "Long", "1/22/20", \
"1/23/20", "1/24/20", "1/25/20", "1/26/20", "1/27/20", "1/28/20", \
"1/29/20", "1/30/20", "1/31/20", "2/1/20", "2/2/20", "2/3/20", \
"2/4/20", "2/5/20", "2/6/20", "2/7/20", "2/8/20", "2/9/20", \
"2/10/20", "2/11/20", "2/12/20", "2/13/20", "2/14/20", "2/15/20", \
"2/16/20", "2/17/20", "2/18/20", "2/19/20", "2/20/20", "2/21/20", \
"2/22/20", "2/23/20", "2/24/20", "2/25/20", "2/26/20", "2/27/20", \
"2/28/20", "2/29/20", "3/1/20", "3/2/20", "3/3/20", "3/4/20", \
"3/5/20", "3/6/20", "3/7/20", "3/8/20", "3/9/20", "3/10/20", \
"3/11/20", "3/12/20", "3/13/20", "3/14/20", "3/15/20", "3/16/20", \
"3/17/20"}

(cv19Deaths[1] // Normal // Keys) == cv19DeathsCSV[[1]]

Out[]:= False
```

Update: As of 3/21/2020, using `SemanticImport` only pulls in data through "3/16/20" (that was the 1st time I used `SemanticImport` on this remote file). Unless anyone other opinions, I'm inclined to think this is a bug and will report it to WRI.

This is the workaround I'm using:

```
cv19DeathsCSVFile = 
  Export["time_series_19-covid-Deaths.csv", 
   Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/\
master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-\
covid-Deaths.csv"]];
cv19Deaths = SemanticImport[cv19DeathsCSVFile];
```

Update 03/24/2020: Johns Hopkins CSSEGIS has deprecated the URL that I used when I created this post. They are no longer updating those files. The new URL is as specified in the following example:

```
cv19Deaths = 
  SemanticImport[
   "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/\
csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_\
deaths_global.csv"];
```

Since this was changed only yesterday, it will take another day or so to retest for the issue. I'll post when I get new results.

Update 03/25/2020: The issue persists. `SemanticImport` is stuck on 03/23/2020. I've submitted a bug report to WRI.

Update 03/26/2020: WRI confirmed this is a bug.

Comment: I *can* reproduce this as well, both in M12.0 and M12.1. I did not download the Deaths data yesterday, and that works fine. I did download the Cases data and there I see the same problem that you describe. As I remember, yesterday I used 12.0, not 12.1

Comment: Same here. Though, I haven't checked 12.0, yet.

Comment: Here is how I work around the issue: cv19DeathsCSVFile = 
  Export["time_series_19-covid-Deaths.csv", 
   Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/\
master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-\
covid-Deaths.csv"]];
cv19Deaths = SemanticImport[cv19DeathsCSVFile];

Comment: I would just use `Import[file, "Dataset"]` if you want to work with Dataset. CSV has been updated quite a bit in Import lately but SemanticImport hasn't received these updates yet.

Comment: @GenericAccountName Can you confirm that `Import` is not affected by the same issue? (It's a bit inconvenient to test because it would require trying it on subsequent days.)

Comment: @Szabolcs, `Import[file, "Dataset"]` does look like it pulls in all the columns. Unfortunately, it looks like this method pulls in each row as a `Dataset` under a top level `Dataset`. It's not as convenient to use in that form.

Comment: @david you can use the HeaderLines option to choose rows/columns as headers

Comment: @GenericAccountName Yes, I saw that below from Itai Seggev

Answer (score 6):

If your only goal is to get a  `Dataset`, then just use

```
cv19DeathsCSV = Import[
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-Deaths.csv",
    "Dataset",
    "HeaderLines" -> 1
]
```

I can't tell you why `SemanticImport` is doing what it does, other than it uses heuristics to be "helpful".  I prefer importing the data as is and then manipulating it myself in Mathematica.

Comment: Can you confirm whether `SemanticImport` will actually cache data downloaded the previous day? That would be very surprising (i.e. bad UX).

Comment: This does look like it pulls in all the columns. Unfortunately, it looks like this method pulls in each row as a `Dataset` under a top level `Dataset`. It's not as convenient to use in that form.

Comment: @Szabolcs I took a quick look at the code (I don't work on `SemanticImport`).  It's certainly not caching anything, but it does use temporary files for some things.  Maybe there's a cleanup problem.  I'd certainly report the issue to support.

Comment: @david I've updated my answer to address this.  `SemanticImport` automatically identifies the first line as a header.  `Import` doesn't attempt to do this, but you can tell it to about headers with an option.

Comment: @ItaiSeggev OK, I like that as an alternative. I think I'd like to wait a bit before accepting to see if someone might answer my original question. I did up-vote you for the good work around. I might use this for most of my Import's in the future as you suggest. Thanks.

Comment: One thing SemanticImport does that other methods do not is automatically generate DateObjects and Entities.  It's possible to code this in as well, but the Import>Export>SemanticImport seems to work.