# SemanticImport returning different data versus Import

Tags: bugs, import

I'm analyzing data for Covid-19 and found an interesting website: "https://covidtracking.com/api/states/daily.csv".  My problem:  using SemanticImport, it seems stuck on the data that I read yesterday even though the site is returning data for today.

Running on MMA v12.1, OSX 10.14.6.

The code is simple:

```
Import["https://covidtracking.com/api/states/daily.csv"]
(* versus *)
SemanticImport["https://covidtracking.com/api/states/daily.csv"]
```

Import returns:

```
(*
{{"date", "state", "positive", "negative", "pending", "hospitalized", 
  "death", "total", "dateChecked", "totalTestResults", 
  "deathIncrease", "hospitalizedIncrease", "negativeIncrease", 
  "positiveIncrease", "totalTestResultsIncrease"}, {20200326, "AK", 
  59, 1801, "", 3, 1, 1860, "2020-03-26T20:00:00Z", 1860, 0, 2, 152, 
  17, 169}, {20200326, "AL", 506, 3593, "", "", 1, 4099, 
  "2020-03-26T20:00:00Z", 4099, 1, 0, 1064, 223, 1287}, {20200326, 
  "AR", 335, 1504, 0, 41, 3, 1839, "2020-03-26T20:00:00Z", 1839, 1, 
  19, 67, 55, 122},...}
*)
```

indicating that there is data available for today (2020-03-26) whereas SemanticImport returns this: 
[image: Dataset view from SemanticImport]

Why isn't SemanticImport starting the data from 20200326 as shown by Import? I have quit out of my current session (closed Mathematica) and restarted thinking that some sort of caching is occurring but that had no effect on the result.

If I cannot figure out why these are different, I'll just have to use Import rather than using SemanticImport.

I'm using the returned data to evaluate the progress of testing for Covid-19 in graphs such as this: 
[image: Testing by date (US only)]

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate. I posted a similar question 8 days ago. I submitted a report to WRI. It's a confirmed bug.

Comment: I didn't realize it was a dup - thanks for letting me know.  Perhaps the code I posted in the answer will help you until they fix the bug.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [SemanticImport vs Import differ on same CSV file?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216536/semanticimport-vs-import-differ-on-same-csv-file)

Comment: It's a bug that several of us are affected by. Please contact Wolfram about it. That should help prioritize it.

Answer (score 1):

The following code does what SemanticImport isn't doing correctly:

```
ImportCSVToDataset[url_] := Block[
  {
   allData = Import[url, "CSV"],
   headerLine,
   dataLines,
   dataLinesAssociation
   },
  {headerLine, dataLines} = TakeDrop[allData, 1];
  headerLine = First@headerLine;
  dataLinesAssociation = 
   Association[Thread[headerLine -> #]] & /@ dataLines;
  Dataset[dataLinesAssociation]
  ]
```

As you can see by this screenshot, it is including the data from 2020-03-26.  [image: Dataset using ImportCSVToDataset]

Comment: The answer in this post shows a better way to do this:https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216536/semanticimport-vs-import-differ-on-same-csv-file  Simply Import[url, "Dataset","HeaderLines"->1]