# SemanticImport not importing new data

Tags: bugs, import

I have a script that uses `SemanticImport` to import CSV content from an internet URL. When I run the same script the following day, the resulting data is not updated. Is there something I'm missing here?

```
data = SemanticImport[
  "https://covidtracking.com/api/v1/us/daily.csv", {Interpreter[
    "Date"], "Integer", "Integer", "Integer", "Integer", "Integer", 
   "Integer", "Integer", "Integer", "Integer", "Integer", "Integer", 
   "String", Interpreter["DateTime"], "Integer", "Integer", "Integer",
    "Integer", "Integer", "String", "Integer", "Integer", "Integer", 
   "Integer", "Integer"}]
```

Comment: When exactly are you running the code? On the main [site](https://covidtracking.com/data) you can check the last update time: `2:13 pm ET`. Running before that time will result in the same data. And for today's data the update time is `4pm ET`. And, I assume, there is no problem with `SemanticImport`.

Comment: The data has definitely been updated since the last time I ran the script; the first row still shows April 20th in Mathematica when it should be April 22nd.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [SemanticImport vs Import differ on same CSV file?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216536/semanticimport-vs-import-differ-on-same-csv-file)

Comment: It's a bug that several of us are affected by. Please contact Wolfram about it. That should help prioritize it.

Comment: That sucks, because I was automating charts from it. Guess I'm going back to Excel and Power Query, which actually work.

Comment: @StevenBuehler You don't have to use `SemanticImport`. Try this `data = Import["https://covidtracking.com/api/v1/us/daily.csv", 
  "Dataset", HeaderLines -> 1]` then `data[All, <|#, "date" -> DateObject[#date], 
   "dateChecked" -> DateObject[#dateChecked]|> &]`

Comment: Just checking if you saw the workaround in the linked 'duplicate' QA.

Comment: I ended up going back to Microsoft Excel and writing a short VBA script to export the charts to images for my purposes. Mathematica is likely too complex and overkill for what the goal was anyway.